# Using a React Server Component in the root layout causes all my pages to be dynamically rendered in NextJS

Tags: next-auth, react-server-components

I have a root layout. I tried integrating next auth to my app by wrappping my whole app with the `<SessionProvider session={session}>` component. That worked on localhost but on deploy to vercel i got the error

`Error: No more than 12 Serverless Functions can be added to a Deployment on the Hobby plan. Create a team (Pro plan) to deploy more. Learn More: https://vercel.link/function-count-limit`

I noticed it was because i marked my root layout with async to dynamically get the server session here is the code below.

```
import { LayoutLinks } from "@/components/LayoutLinks";
import Nav from "@/components/Nav";
import SessionProvider from "@/components/auth/ClientSessionProvider";
import { GlobalDataProvider } from "@/hooks/useGlobalData";
import { Metadata } from "next";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
import "./globals.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Payroll system",
  description: "Payroll System",
};

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const session = await getServerSession();

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
          <GlobalDataProvider>
            <Toaster />
            <main className="min-h-screen flex flex-col">
              <Nav />
              <div className="flex flex-grow">
                <LayoutLinks /> {children}
              </div>
            </main>
          </GlobalDataProvider>
        </SessionProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Now remember i have no way of not passing the session object to the provider component. It is not marked as required(i.e ) TS does not error when i dont provide it. But i cant successfully login from the frontend. Its like the frontend is never aware of whether or not a user is signed in so that keeps redirecting them to the sign in page.

I tried a much granular approach to only surroun the components that needed the session with the provider. I started by tryng it out around a single profile picture component that lived inside my navbar.

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import Image from "next/image";
import globe from "../public/globe.svg";
import logo from "../public/logo.svg";
import notificationBell from "../public/notification-bell.svg";
import { ProfileInfo } from "./ProfileInfo";
import SessionProvider from "./auth/ClientSessionProvider";

const Nav = async () => {
  const session = await getServerSession();
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-between items-center py-3 bg-white px-12">
      <div className="flex items-center">
        <Image src={logo} className="object-cover mr-2" alt="logo" />
        <p className="font-semibold montserrat">HRM</p>
      </div>
      <div className="flex gap-x-6 items-center">
        <div className="flex gap-x-2">
          <Image src={globe} alt="Globe" />
          <p>EN</p>
        </div>
        <Image src={notificationBell} alt="Globe" />
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
          <ProfileInfo />
        </SessionProvider>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

That did not work either. I think its because thr `Nav` component is inside the layout component.

Now here is my question.

**How can i succcessfully pass in the session to the session provider? Can i use state to fetch the session the same way we used to do in the old days with useEffect? Is there a way to opt out of RSC ?** I dont wan to upgrade my plan i cant afford it.

**Also is there a way to just surround my whole app with the session provider? So that i can access the session wherever i want without using `Layout.tsx`**

Please help.

PS: I did try creating a HOC which kind of abstracts the react server component but that did not work unfortunately. If an RSC is in my app all my pages get lambda death signs.

[image: an image of my vercel logs]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue 5 min ago. mennaged to fix is
and now my build report looks like this:

```
Route (app)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ λ /                                    22.8 kB         132 kB
├ ○ /_not-found                          875 B          81.5 kB
├ λ /api/auth/[...nextauth]              0 B                0 B
├ ○ /chat                                150 B          80.8 kB
├ ○ /dashboard                           23.6 kB         133 kB
├ ○ /error/register-first                176 B          87.8 kB
├ ○ /mailbox                             150 B          80.8 kB
├ ○ /profile                             150 B          80.8 kB
└ ○ /settings                            150 B          80.8 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all            80.6 kB
  ├ chunks/472-80f1176fdc677c8c.js       27.5 kB
  ├ chunks/fd9d1056-8f5a27328eb1acae.js  51.1 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-471080d33f00ab88.js  230 B
  └ chunks/webpack-ab36b6b20a4f1ea6.js   1.82 kB
```

I had the same setup like you did. So here is what i have now:

app/common/providers/Providers/SessionProvider.tsx (obv, the path does not metter)

```
'use client';

import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';

const Provider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
};

export default Provider;
```

Have layout.tsx like this:

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning className={`${inter.variable} `}>
      <body>
        <ThemeProvider>
          <SessionProvider>
            <NavBar />
            {children}
          </SessionProvider>
          <Toaster expand={true} />
          <ModalProvider />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Additionaly I am using middleware

```
export { default } from 'next-auth/middleware';

export const config = { matcher: ['/communication', '/dashboard'] };
```

have magic link + gmail verification. works fine

Comment: okay on your layout.tsx you don't seem to use the provider created on the SessionProvider file. Is this by design or is it a mistake?

Comment: https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/adding-authentication
take a look here
they do not use provider at all on their nextjs.org 

frankly the way next auth documentation is written it rather strange. They showing some codesnippets and saying that snippets for AppRouter but they are not :D 

It seems like we can ommit using provider all together with next 13+ based on the link I sent above 

sorry, I might not sound convincing and this is fine. by no mean I am an expert. jest sharing what i found and what prevented my app ALL PAGES from being server side rendered.